# Why does my solution of the closed form formula for the Fibonacci sequence differ from the actual solution by a sign?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions, fibonacci-numbers

I have $a_{n}=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$ with $a_0=0$ and $a_1=1$.

I've found the generating function $G(x)=\frac{x}{1-x-x^2}$. Solving $1-x-x^2=0$ gives the solutions $\alpha_1=\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $\alpha_2=\frac{-1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$. Then, using partial fractions, I found: $$\frac{x}{1-x-x^2}=\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt5}\alpha_1}{x-\alpha_1}-\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\alpha_2}{x-\alpha_2},$$
so that
\begin{align}
G(x)&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}( \frac{\alpha_1}{x-\alpha_1} - \frac{\alpha_2}{x-\alpha_2})\\
& =\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} (\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\alpha_1}x-1}- \frac{1}{\frac{1}{\alpha_2}x-1})\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} (\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{\alpha_2}x} - \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{\alpha_1}x})\\
& = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} (\sum((\frac{1}{\alpha_2})^n-(\frac{1}{\alpha_1})^n)x^n,
\end{align}

So that the solution is $a_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}((\frac{1}{\alpha_2})^n-(\frac{1}{\alpha_1})^n)$.

$\frac{1}{\alpha_1}=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{\alpha_2}=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$. Substituting these values get us:

$$a_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}((\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^n-(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^n),$$

which actually differs from the correct answer only by a negative sign.

Comment: I don't see any mistake so far in what you show.  I would consider checking your partial fractions.

Comment: @Doug: I checked and couldn't find my mistake there.

Comment: There is a sign error in your $\alpha_2$ and also in $\alpha_1$. You need to multiply both by $-1$. Sub them in to confirm

Comment: @fGDu94 $x=(-1\pm \sqrt{5})/2$ are the solutions to $1-x-x^2=0$.

Comment: Have a go at substituting them in and see what you find

Comment: @fGDu94: I did a sanity check. They do indeed work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** It seems we have

\begin{align*}
\frac{x}{1-x-x^2}=\color{blue}{-}\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt5}\alpha_1}{x-\alpha_1}\color{blue}{+}\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\alpha_2}{x-\alpha_2}
\end{align*}

Comment: But now the RHS equals $-\frac{x}{1-x-x^2}$.

Comment: @J.Doe: I don't think so. You might want to check it again.

Comment: You are right. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @J.Doe: You're welcome! :-)